# Getting value from checkbox checked in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, datatable, tableadapter

I have problem about getting the value from checkbox checked in `datagridview`. I want to get all the Id where the checkbox checked, but I only got the latest checked only.

Here is my code:

```
string Id = "";

ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter tam = new ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter();    
ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable dtm = new ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_members.Rows)    
{        
    if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && (Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
    {
        Id= row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        // using Id to display data in crystal report viewer  
        // but only read the latest checkbox value

        dtm = tam.GetDataBy_SearchId(Id); 

        // in my dataset (ds_utility), I wrote the query like this
        // SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE (Id = ?)
    }
}
```

How to write a query to get all the value?

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting "dtm" object in the loop. So in that case after each iteration it will contain data from current Id. Naturally after last iteration it will contain data from the last Id only.

Comment: @vaxlt thanks for replying.. can you explain more where should I put "dtm" or how to write the right query in order to get all the value?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you have multiple options:

Create list of ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable and add table to the list after each iteration. This is the simpliest way but it will give you problems going forward, because you will have to iterate throught multiple tables first. It would look like this:

```
string Id = "";

ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter tam = new    ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter();       List<ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable> dtm = new List<ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_members.Rows)     {         if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && (Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true) {
    Id= row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    // using Id to display data in crystal report viewer  
    // but only read the latest checkbox value

    dtm.Add(tam.GetDataBy_SearchId(Id));

    // in my dataset (ds_utility), I wrote the query like this
    // SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE (Id = ?) } }
```

But best option in your case would be to change the sql query and instead of passing one Id, pass in the concatenated list of Id's. You can achieve this by modifying your sql to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE Id in (?)
```

And change the code to look like:

```
string Id = "";

ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter tam = new ds_utilityTableAdapters.tbl_membersTableAdapter();    
ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable dtm = new ds_utility.tbl_membersDataTable();
List<string> idList = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_members.Rows)    
{        
    if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && (Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
    {
        Id= row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        // using Id to display data in crystal report viewer  
        // but only read the latest checkbox value

    idList.Add(Id);
    }
}

dtm = tam.GetDataBy_SearchId(string.Join(",", idList));
```